# Bing Translate API: GetTranslations method not allowed

Tags: api, http, translate, bing

I'm using an HTTP API for Bing Translate. Such methods as Speak and Translate work perfectly. But GetTranslations doesn't. Any request to http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetTranslations returns "Method not allowed". What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is not allowed for 'http'.
You can use the 'Ajax' like request below:

http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/GetTranslations?appId=31C738345474CF52FD6F313331A7B00837031F17&text=rabbit&from=en&to=ru&maxTranslations=5